# How can I convert the hex hash ID of a stake pool to "pool1..." format in Javascript or TypeScript?

Tags: stake-pool, hash

I want to convert the hash of a pool in hexadecimal to `pool1...` format

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding is called Bech32.

I suspect that [cardano-addresses](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses) can do this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the bech32 command (which comez in the cardano-wallet package, if you don't already have it):

`bech32 pool <<< <hex_pool_id>`